# blocking URL stream doesn't reflect changes in data

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm working on a project that uses the Telegram API to communicate. Since it is written in C++, the only viable library for this is [tgbot-cpp](https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp), but it is too big, slow and unreliable for my purposes.

Because it wasn't reliable, I wanted to write my very own, and very minimal Telegram Bot API that doesn't have any dependencies (whereas tgbot-cpp has 8 or more DLL dependencies). I'm using Win32 since it doesn't have to be cross-platform.

I use `URLOpenBlockingStream()` to make a simple request and read the data returned (the Telegram Bot API returns a simple serialized JSON object). The code looks something like the following (yes, the variable naming and structure could be better, but I don't care about that for the time being, I'll have time to optimize it later. The `stringstream`s are used to convert to `wstring` because it's mandated by the function, and the rest of my program doesn't use wide strings):

```
std::string TGBot::makeUrlQuery(const std::string& queryUrl)
{
    std::wstringstream ss;
    ss << queryUrl.c_str();
    IStream* stream;
    const HRESULT result = URLOpenBlockingStream(nullptr, ss.str().c_str(), &stream, 0, nullptr);

    if (result != 0)
    {
        return {};
    }

    char buffer[100]{};
    unsigned long bytesRead{};
    std::stringstream sss{};
    stream->Read(buffer, 100, &bytesRead);
    while (bytesRead > 0U)
    {
        sss.write(buffer, bytesRead);
        stream->Read(buffer, 100, &bytesRead);
    }

    stream->Release();
    return sss.str();
}
```

Now, this works well in itself, meaning that it reads the serialized JSON object from the stream successfully, and I can process it with ease.

**The problem is this**: I have to use this in a listening loop that calls the function every few seconds to see if there are new messages. On the first start-up, everything works fine, but if I send a new message, then the JSON object should update, but the function still returns the old JSON object, even though the request is valid (I can copy the URL into my browser and clearly see that the API responds accordingly). If I don't clear the message queue and restart the program, then everything works fine the first time around with the new JSON object being read.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: `std::wstringstream` is not the right way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. Also, polling the Telegram API every few seconds is an inefficient way to get new messages.  Telegram can actively send new messages to you so you don't have to poll for them.

Comment: Sounds like the JSON is being cached outside of your program's control, such as in an intermediate web proxy. Unfortunately, `URLOpenBlockingStream()` doesn't have a flag to force the URL to be reloaded fresh. Try using the WinInet API instead (`InternetOpenUrl()`, `InternetReadFile()`, etc), which has such a flag (it will also avoid the need for wide strings, since it has functions available for narrow ANSI strings).

Comment: Yes, I know that isn't the right way to convert to a wstring, but that, as I already said, can be optimized later. If you are referring to webhooks and long-polling then yes, it is a more efficient way to do that, but I explicitly avoided it since it would basically force me to use boost.ASIO or some other library and it would either have a dll dependency or would make the executable markably bigger.

Comment: Also, thanks for the answer, I will try it as soon as possible.